# Indents appearing before <span> tags in Windows Phone

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-7, html-email

Composing an HTML email we've encountered an odd issue where indents appear inside spans for no apparent reason.

I've included the HTML below, but as far as I can see there is no padding, margin, etc applied to the spans. None of the inline styles seem like they could be the cause. Assuming I'm missing something very basic here.

Indents to the left of the bottom two phone numbers:
(picture is from a Windows 7 HTC phone test from the Litmus email testing app)
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

                  <style type="text/css">

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
body img.banner {max-width: 300px !important; height: auto !important;}
table {max-width: 300px overflow:visible; width: auto; }
}

div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }

span { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

.appleLinks a {color:#400400; text-decoration:none;}

.appleLinksGray a:link,.appleLinksGray a:visited {color:#808080;}

.appleLinksGrayClean a:link,.appleLinksGrayClean a:visited {color:#808080; text-decoration:none;}

</style> 
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
        <table style="background-color: #ffffff; margin: auto; font-family: 'trebuchet ms', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="627">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><img class="banner" src="" alt="Alt" width="625" height="100" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; font-family: 'trebuchet ms', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top: 20px; color: #400400;"><p>Dear ~goesBy~,<br />
                      <br>
                      Text</p>
                      <p>Regards,<br>
                        Text
                          <br>
                          <br>
                      </p>
                      <p><span class="appleLinks">Address<br>
<br>
5:00 – 7:00 pm
                     </span></p>
                      <p><b style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000;">Name<br />
    </b><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; white-space: nowrap; color: #808080; font-size: 8pt;">Manager<br />
      <br />
      </span><b><span style="font-family: 'times new roman', times, serif; color: #00644c; font-size: 10pt;"><br />
        COMPANY </span></b><br />
  <span class="appleLinksGrayClean" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #808080; font-size: 8pt;">Address Line 1</span><br />
  <span class="appleLinksGrayClean" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #808080; font-size: 8pt;">Address Line 2</span><br />
    <span class="appleLinksGray" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #808080; font-size: 8pt;">111.111.1111</span><br />
    <span class="appleLinksGray" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #808080; font-size: 8pt;">111.111.1111 direct</span><br />
    <span class="appleLinksGray" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #808080; font-size: 8pt;">111.111.1111 mobile</span><br />
    <a href="mailto:person@example.com" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #808080; font-size: 8pt;"><span class="appleLinksGray" >person@example.com</span></a></p></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top: 20px;" colspan="2">
                    <div style="text-align: left; font-family: verdana; color: #333333; font-size: 9px;">Copyright</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the spaces before `<!DOCTYPE`. Maybe this triggers some compatibility-mode

Comment: Yes, even though it's not shown there, have tried that. I'll update the example.

Comment: What happens if you add a word to the preceding line? e.g. `111.111.1111 test`

Comment: Tried adding the word 'test' and it has no affect on the lines below.

Comment: the phone numbers are recognized and some extra HTML is added within the page so that they are clickable (touchable) and be called directly. Same issues can be expect on browsers with skype plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check for hidden characters?  Sometimes when you copy paste code, special characters get included.  Mostly from a character set difference.  Try deleting all white space between the html tags.

Comment: Yes that was it. Simply by deleting the white space between the tags the extra indents disappear. Thanks, surprised it was such a simple solution.

Comment: Yeah, thats usually usually what it is.  When you copy / paste text for sources with different encodings, it can add hidden characters that just look like white space.

Answer (score 0):

try removing `colspan='2'` from all the `td`s

Comment: No luck, just ran a new test in Litmus, thought that would do it too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend removing the extraneous code on all of your lines to eliminate the possibility that the rendering engine is picking up additional spaces at the beginning of each `<span>`

```
<span class="appleLinksGray" style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color: #808080; font-size: 8pt;">111.111.1111<br />111.111.1111 direct<br />111.111.1111 mobile</span>
```

I've seen IE add spaces (especially, in table layouts) just by having a carriage return in my code (to help me read it easier).

Comment: Thanks. We actually need that CSS to override apple iOS links, but I'm going to try it without just to see if that is in fact the issue.

Comment: It didn't work -- but I think I realized why this is happening. Windows Phone is adding its own links to those last two numbers because it 'see' tel and fax next to them. Not sure if there is a way to deal with that.

Comment: How about styling those: `a[href^="tel"] { padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important; }` May just need the CSS, if the device is appending it on its own.